# County level data on technical training/apprenticeships?

Tags: data-request, education

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this but has anyone ever worked with county-level data regarding technical training/vocational programs/community college certificates?

I'm looking for some dataset that might have summaries at the county level for any of these things like for example how https://www.doleta.gov/oa/data_statistics2016.cfm offers it at the state level.

If this is the wrong place to ask please direct me to the social sciences analysis page?

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search gives you this-

http://data.uis.unesco.org/

https://data.world/datasets/education

https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Education/datasets

http://www.oecd.org/education/publicationsdocuments/datasets/

https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/conference/download.cgi?db_name=CSAE2018&paper_id=384